# Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerClient is not defined

Tags: backbone.js, swagger, openapi

we try to update [swagger-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-client) from 2.0 to 3.0, but after we update it started throwing error for SwaggerClient is not defined.
[image]

Comment: in gulpfile the import was wrong, it is corrected and it fixes the issue. Thanks